# Execute JS before PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('
//some html
<script type="text/javascript" src="iniNA_perso.js"></script>
//some more html
')

$checkbox = $dom->getElementById("mycheckbox1");
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The script dynamically appends checkboxes but the script is not executed before the PHP code ($dom->getElementById("mycheckbox1");
So, naturally, the checkbox can't be found...

How can I execute the JS script before the PHP is executed so I can select the checkbox?

I tried to place $dom->saveHTML(); before the assignation of $checkbox but no change...

Comment: No. PHP is executed on the server, and only then, the generated page is sent to the browser, which executes the JS code.

Comment: impossible PHP runs before JavaScript. You need to use Ajax or submit a form.